# pandas using melt to create lookup table

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` `df` of size 24x13 which appears as (I have displayed truncated version of 24x13 array which represents 12 months and 24 hours):

```
HE        1    2     3    4    
0    1  1.8   2.5  3.5  8.5  
1    2  2.6   2.9  4.3  8.7  
2    3  4.4   2.3  5.3  4.3  
3    4  2.6   2.1  4.2  5.3
```

How do I change this to look up table for each combination of hour and month and display the value in third column as follows:

```
Hour Month Value
1     1    1.8
1     2    2.5
1     3    3.5
```

I am trying the following and variation of it but this is not working:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=range(1,24), value_vars=range(1,12))

Edit 1:
df.columns
Index([u'HE', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], dtype='object')

df.shape
(24, 13)
```

Comment: Is 'HE' the index name or the title of the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.set_index('HE').stack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   HE level_1    0
0   1       1  1.8
1   1       2  2.5
2   1       3  3.5
3   1       4  8.5
4   2       1  2.6
```

OR using melt

```
df.melt(id_vars='HE').sort_values(by=['HE','variable']
```

Output:

```
    HE variable  value
0    1        1    1.8
4    1        2    2.5
8    1        3    3.5
12   1        4    8.5
1    2        1    2.6
```

Comment: Can you show the melt representation .. your code does the job but I am trying to learn the melt also? Thanks.